# Repository Unit of work with ObjectContext

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am learning unit of work at [google](http://74.125.236.81/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=639&source=hp&q=repository%20and%20unit%20of%20work%20patterns%20with%20entity%20framework&pbx=1&oq=Repository%20and%20U&aq=1&aqi=g3g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=sc&gs_upl=0l0l1l1863l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b022d9a00a4d3080&pf=p&pdl=300).
But most of the example I get is about with [unit of work with DbContext](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).
So please could anyone give me example of Unit of work with ObjectContext.

**[Just my thinking, May be not correct.]**
I don't like code first pattern because it need me to write properties classes(with get set methods) myself.

But by using edmx file with objectContext, i don't need to create properties classes which take time.

Comment: I think if you change the DbContext word by ObjectContext it'll work...

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of articles on this.

- [Entity Framework POCO (EF4): Generic Repository and Unit of Work
  Prototype](http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/)
- [Entity Framework 4 POCO, Repository and Specification Pattern](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/)

These abstractions may not fit to your problem exactly. So understand the concepts behind the Entity Framework before going into making abstractions.

Comment: thank @Eranga for your references, now i am reading your references.